# Is this proof of chain rule correct?

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry the first time I had many errors in writing the proof out. They have been fixed

I did the classic division by zero proof and was pointed out wrong, so I try the opposite approach
$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$
$$g'(x_0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$
$$\Rightarrow g'(f(x_0))=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{f(x)-f(x_0)}$$
(since $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$)

Multiplying them together:
$$f'(x_0)\cdot g' (f(x_0)) =\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \cdot \frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{f(x)-f(x_0)}$$$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{x-x_0}=(g\circ f)(x_0)'$$
Is there anything wrong with this proof?

Comment: What on earth is that expression for $g'(x)$?  And you have retained the possibility that the denominator $f(x)-f(x_0)=0$.

Comment: The end result is wrong so the proof is wrong. $(f\circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$

Comment: Sorry the first time I had many errors in writing the proof out. They have been fixed. Can you guys view it again

Comment: There is a conspicuous error in what appears above: $$\text{wrong}: \qquad f'(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ $$\text{right}: \qquad f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ The last line has $f'(x)\cdot g'(f(x))$ where you need $f'(x_0)\cdot g'(f(x_0))$ and $(g\circ f)'(x)$ where you need $(g\circ f)'(x_0). \qquad$

Comment: ok, Now I've fixed that problem.  Also not that you don't need to write $a.b$; you can instead write $a\cdot b.\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

The problem is points where $f(x)-f(x_0)$ is $0$ even though $x-x_0$ is not $0$.

Instead of $\dfrac{g(f(x)) - g(f(x_0))}{f(x) - f(x_0)},$ you can use a piecewise defined function
$$
\left.\begin{cases} \dfrac{g(f(x)) - g(f(x_0))}{f(x) - f(x_0)}, & \text{if } f(x) - f(x_0), \\[10pt]
g'(f(x_0)), & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} \right\}.
$$

**PS:** An extreme case is when $f(x)$ is constant on some open interval containing $x_0$.  In that case $g(f(x))$ is also constant on that interval and so we must have $f'(x_0) = 0$ and $(g\circ f)'(x_0)=0$, and so it is true that $f'(x_0)\cdot g'(f(x_0)) = (g\circ f)'(x_0)$, but as $x$ is approaching $x_0$ your expression $$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\cdot \frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{f(x)-f(x_0)} \tag 1$$is undefined because the second fraction is $0/0$ even while $x\ne x_0$.

A less extreme case is when the set of values of $x$ for which $f(x)-f(x_0)=0$ contains some sequence approaching $x_0$.  In that case, there is no open interval about $x_0$ within which the second fraction in the product $(1)$ is always defined.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why that will be a problem?

Comment: Dividing by zero causes many problems, like 1=0.

Comment: @JustinYoung Can you point out where I did the dividing by zero?

Comment: Is this the second fraction:$\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{f(x)-f(x_0)}$? Is this whole thing invalid too then:$g'(f(x_0))=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))}{f(x)-f(x_0)}$?

Comment: @billy9797 : Where you did the dividing by zero is explained at some length in my answer above. $\qquad$